# Show that $p^*(\mathbb{R}^N)=L^*$

Tags: matrices, statistics

Let $L$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^N$ with dimension $k$ and such that $L=\left \{ A\beta \mid  \beta\in \mathbb{R}^k\right \}$, where $A$ is a $N\times k$ matrix. Let $C$ be a $1\times k$ non-zero matrix and define $L^*=\left \{ A\beta \mid  \beta\in \mathbb{R}^k \wedge C\beta=0  \right \}$. It is clear that $L^*$ has dimension $k-1$ and is a subspace of $L$.

I need to show that $p^*(\mathbb{R}^N)=L^*$ where

$p^*(x)=P^*x = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx-A(A^TA)^{-1}C^T(C(A^TA)^{-1}C^T)^{-1}C(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx$

I have already shown $p^*(\mathbb{R}^N)\supseteq L^*$, but I do have problem with the other inclusion.

Comment: In what sense do you mean the matrix C is non-degenerate? That's a highly overloaded term :)

Comment: Ups, I mean non-zero matrix :). It is edited now, thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's true that $L^*$ is $k-1$ dimensional unless you have some further conditions on $A$. Note the Null space of $C$ is certainly $k-1$ dimensional but $A$ could be the zero matrix for all we know.

Comment: $A$ sends $\mathbb{R}^k$ bijectively into $L$. So it is most certainly not the zero matrix.

Comment: Ah you said that in a very roundabout way by specifying the dimension of $L$ sorry I missed that

Comment: $A$ is N x k so $A^TA$ and $(A^TA)^{-1}$ are both k x k. Since $C^T$ is k x 1 and C is 1 x k we can conclude that whole middle term of the 2nd part of $p^*$ : 
$(C(A^TA)^{-1}C^T)$ is constant right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The term right for that is also a constant.

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm not there yet. The $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx$ term is the orthogonal projection of $x$ into $L$. It feels like there is a geometric interpretation to the 2nd term but I'm not sure what it is. Anything further you can share about it?

Comment: My idea was to choose a basis $(v_1,v_2,..,v_{k-1})$ for the null space for $C$ and extend it to $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $v_k$. Now transform with those $A$, so I get a basis for $L$ namely $(Av_1,..,Av_k)$. It is easy to show $p^*(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\alpha _iAv_i )= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\alpha _iAv_i \in L^*$. So I basically need to show that $p^*(Av_k) = 0$, cause any $x \in L$ can be written as $ x = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\alpha _iAv_i$.